# Linux bash: Multiple variable assignment

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variable-assignment, multiple-variable-return

Does exist in linux bash something similar to the following code in PHP:

```
list($var1, $var2, $var3) = function_that_returns_a_three_element_array() ;
```

i.e. you assign in one sentence a corresponding value to 3 different variables.

Let's say I have the bash function `myBashFuntion` that writes to stdout the string "qwert asdfg zxcvb".
Is it possible to do something like:

```
(var1 var2 var3) = ( `myBashFuntion param1 param2` )
```

The part at the left of the equal sign is not valid syntax of course. I'm just trying to explain what I'm asking for.

What does work, though, is the following:

```
array = ( `myBashFuntion param1 param2` )
echo ${array[0]} ${array[1]} ${array[2]}
```

But an indexed array is not as descriptive as plain variable names.
However, I could just do:

```
var1 = ${array[0]} ; var2 = ${array[1]} ; var3 = ${array[2]}
```

But those are 3 more statements that I'd prefer to avoid.

I'm just looking for a shortcut syntax. Is it possible?

Answer (score 290, accepted):

First thing that comes into my mind:

```
read -r a b c <<<$(echo 1 2 3) ; echo "$a|$b|$c"
```

output is, unsurprisingly

```
1|2|3
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get this to work if the first variable contains a space?

Comment: @Michael Using `read -d "\n" v1 v2 <<<$(cmd)` works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @LeeNetherton, good point, though I'm not sure if one needs the return status of echo command :-) I think at the time of writing the answer bash supporting this syntax was less common (as in installed by default), though I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker sure, the return status of `echo` is pointless, but I was using this technique to return multiple values from a script that I did care about the return status. I thought I would share my findings.

Comment: @SevenHong, sure, check section `3.6.7 Here Strings` of https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html — basically, it supplies what follows after expansion to the stdin of the command being invoked.

Comment: For safety you should use: `read -r`: `do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`

Comment: @LeeNetherton Is it really working? I did this: `function p2 { echo v1 v2; return 5; }` and then: `read a b < <(p2); echo $?` and I got `0` instead of expected `5`. Can you provide working example, please?

Comment: Or `read -r a b c < <(echo 1 2 3) ; echo "$a|$b|$c"` just to use Process Substitution, instead of Here String + Command Substitution.

Comment: @ericbn, For what I can tell by other comments (some apparently not available anymore), I probably was of the opinion that process substitution was less widely available at that point. Not sure whether I really was of that opinion and whether the opinion was correct, it was 12 years ago :) But yes, you're right, that's an option, regardless.

Answer (score 22):

I wanted to assign the values to an array. So, extending [Michael Krelin's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952480/5337834), I did:

```
read a[{1..3}] <<< $(echo 2 4 6); echo "${a[1]}|${a[2]}|${a[3]}"
```

which yields:

```
2|4|6
```

as expected.

Comment: To put the values in an array there is already a simple solution which I mentioned in the question: `a=( $(echo 2 4 6) ) ; echo ${a[0]} ${a[1]} ${a[2]}`

Comment: Yes, I had overlooked that. I would argue, though, that my suggestion is better suited to assigning larger arrays.

Comment: @soundray Your solution uses expansion and a herestring, bash being what it is I doubt it will perform well in that scenario (but I didn't check).

Comment: For safety you should use: `read -r`: `do not allow backslashes to escape any characters`

Answer (score 5):

I think this might help...

In order to break down user inputted dates (mm/dd/yyyy) in my scripts, I store the day, month, and year into an array, and then put the values into separate variables as follows:

```
DATE_ARRAY=(`echo $2 | sed -e 's/\// /g'`)
MONTH=(`echo ${DATE_ARRAY[0]}`)
DAY=(`echo ${DATE_ARRAY[1]}`)
YEAR=(`echo ${DATE_ARRAY[2]}`)
```

Comment: Why not avoid 4 subshells plus an extra sed process, and just do all that in one line: `IFS=/ read -r m d y < <(echo 12/29/2009)`

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes you have to do something funky. Let's say you want to read from a command (the date example by SDGuero for example) but you want to avoid multiple forks.

```
read month day year << DATE_COMMAND
 $(date "+%m %d %Y")
DATE_COMMAND
echo $month $day $year
```

You could also pipe into the read command, but then you'd have to use the variables within a subshell:

```
day=n/a; month=n/a; year=n/a
date "+%d %m %Y" | { read day month year ; echo $day $month $year; }
echo $day $month $year
```

results in...

```
13 08 2013
n/a n/a n/a
```

Comment: The `read` command does not happen in a subshell because of the braces, it's because you've got the read command on the right side of the pipe. You need to run the `read` command in the current shell, which you can do like `read day month year <<< \`date "+%d %m %Y"\``

Comment: No -- the `read` _happens_ but the scope of the variables it reads into falls out of scope when the subshell of the pipeline ends.

Comment: My comment was about the reason _why_ the read happens in a subshell, and I realize now I misread what you wrote. I thought you meant that the subshell was created because you used the curly braces around the compound statement. But! The reason you gave that example was to avoid forking, and but won't the subshell fork, too?

Comment: The first example requires exactly one fork: so that bash can launch the date command.  In the second example, you set up a pipeline between date and your sub-shell. I think bash these days is clever enough not to actually fork into the subshell, but I'm not sure about that. At any rate, it _looks_ like it would :)

Answer (score 0):

Chapter 5 of the [Bash Cookbook](http://www.bashcookbook.com/) by O'Reilly, discusses (at some length) the reasons for the requirement in a variable assignment that there be no spaces around the '=' sign

```
MYVAR="something"
```

The explanation has something to do with distinguishing between the name of a command and a variable (where '=' may be a valid argument).

This all seems a little like justifying after the event, but in any case there is no mention of a method of assigning to a list of variables.

Comment: Yes, I know. I just added extra spaces here and there for the sake of readability

Comment: Indeed that's a poor motivation: What if '`;`' is a valid argument?  When I write `ls ; cd` it still calls `ls` and `cd` despite the spaces.  If I want to list directories called `;` and `cd` I can just type `ls ';' cd`.

Answer (score -3):

let var1=var2=var3=0 
or 
var1=var2=var3="Default value"