# How to get the IP address from $SSH_CLIENT

Tags: bash

$SSH_CLIENT has IP address with some port info, and echo $SSH_CLIENT gives me '10.0.40.177 52335 22', and Running

`if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] ;
then
  for i in $SSH_CLIENT
  do
      echo $i
  done
fi`

gives me

- 10.0.40.177
- 52335
- 22

And I see the first element is the IP address.

Q : How can I get the first element of $SSH_CLIENT?
${SSH_CLIENT[0]} doesn't work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
sshvars=($SSH_CLIENT)
echo "${sshvars[0]}"
```

or:

```
echo "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}"
```

Comment: For the clueless (like me) the second is doing “parameter substitution.” Here's a reference: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html

Comment: or `echo ${SSH_CLIENT// *}`

Answer (score 7):

you can use `set --` eg

```
$ SSH_CLIENT="10.0.40.177 52335 22"
$ set -- $SSH_CLIENT
$ echo $1  # first "element"
10.0.40.177
$ echo $2  # second "element"
52335
$ echo $3
22
```

Answer (score 3):

For strings, as is the case here, the `<<<` operator may be used:

```
$ read ipaddress outport inport <<< $SSH_CLIENT
```

See e.g: [Linux Bash: Multiple variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952404/linux-bash-multiple-variable-assignment).
Don't do this with binary input though: [Is there a binary safe <<< in bash?](https://superuser.com/questions/342982/is-there-a-binary-safe-triple-less-than-operator-in-bash)

Comment: There's no reason to do `$(echo ...)`, it's the same as just including the variable.

Comment: Right you are. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer `awk`:

```
$ SSH_CLIENT="10.0.40.177 52335 22"
$ echo $SSH_CLIENT|awk '{print $1}' # first element
10.0.40.177
$ echo $SSH_CLIENT|awk '{print $2}' # second element
52335
$ echo $SSH_CLIENT|awk '{print $3}' # third element
22
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this in my .bash_profile, and it works beautifully.

```
if [ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ] ;
    then
    echo $SSH_CLIENT | awk '{print $1}'
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get it programmatic way via ssh library (https://code.google.com/p/sshxcute)

```
public static String getIpAddress() throws TaskExecFailException{
    ConnBean cb = new ConnBean(host, username, password);
    SSHExec ssh = SSHExec.getInstance(cb);
    ssh.connect();
    CustomTask sampleTask = new ExecCommand("echo \"${SSH_CLIENT%% *}\"");
    String Result = ssh.exec(sampleTask).sysout;
    ssh.disconnect();   
    return Result;
}
```