# Bash: Read into multiple local scope variables

Tags: bash

According to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952480/582917

I can read in and therefore assign multiple variables.

However I want those variables to be local to a bash function so it doesn't pollute the global scope.

Is there a way to do something like:

```
func () {
    local read a b <<< $(echo 123 435)
    echo $a
}
func
echo $a
```

The above doesn't work. What is a good way of reading into local variables?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You were almost there: you just have to define the variables as `local`, but beforehand instead of in the `read` declaration:

```
func () {
     local a b
     read a b <<< $(echo 123 435)
     echo $a
}
```

#### Test

```
$ func 
123
$ echo $a
$
```

Answer (score 6):

Just declare the variables to be local on one line, and use them on a separate line:

```
$ a=5
$ func() {
    local a b
    read a b <<< "foo bar"
    echo $a
}
$ func
foo
$ echo $a
5
```