# Store local variable from user input in bash?

Tags: bash

When getting user input via the `read` command and storing in a variable. For example:

```
get_username() {
  read -p "Enter your username: " username
}

another_function() {
  echo $username
}

get_username; another_function;
```

The `$username` variable is now available globally within the entire script. Is there a way to restrict the scope of the variable stored from the user input or delete it after it is no longer needed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash: Read into multiple local scope variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991799/bash-read-into-multiple-local-scope-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variables are global unless specifically declared to be local.

```
get_username () {
  local username
  read -p "Enter your username: " username
}
```

Comment: You probably want `-r` as well in case someone fat-fingers their username.

Answer (score 1):

you can use unset to unset the variable or local to limit the visibility

```
get_username() {
  read -p "Enter your username: " username
}

another_function() {
  echo $username
  unset username

}

get_username; another_function; another_function;
```