# Bash read function returns error code when using new line delimiter

Tags: bash, io-redirection, built-in

I have a script that I am returning multiple values from, each on a new line. To capture those values as bash variables I am using the `read` builtin (as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952480/341459)).

The problem is that when I use the new line character as the delimiter for `read`, I seem to always get a non-zero exit code. This is playing havoc with the rest of my scripts, which check the result of the operation.

Here is a cut-down version of what I am doing:

```
$ read -d '\n' a b c < <(echo -e "1\n2\n3"); echo $?; echo $a $b $c
1
1 2 3
```

Notice the exit status of 1.

I don't want to rewrite my script (the `echo` command above) to use a different delimiter (as it makes sense to use new lines in other places of the code).

How do I get `read` to play nice and return a zero exit status when it successfully reads 3 values?

**Update**

Hmmm, it seems that I may be using the "delimiter" wrongly. From the man page:

> ```
> -d *delim* 
>
>   The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line,
>   rather than newline.
> ```

Therefore, one way I could achieve the desired result is to do this:

```
read -d '#' a b c < <(echo -e "1\n2\n3\n## END ##"); echo $?; echo $a $b $c
```

Perhaps there's a nicer way though?

Comment: You should write `-d $'\n'`. Otherwise, the delimiter is backslash (which is likely never really read since you don't use the `-r` option to `read`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-d` is the wrong thing to use here. What you really want is three separate calls to read:

```
{ read a; read b; read c; } < <(echo $'1\n2\n3\n')
```

Be sure that the input ends with a newline so that the final `read` has an exit status of 0.

If you don't know how many lines are in the input ahead of time, you need to read the values into an array. In `bash` 4, that takes just a single call to `readarray`:

```
readarray -t arr < <(echo $'1\n2\n3\n')
```

Prior to `bash` 4, you need to use a loop:

```
while read value; do
    arr+=("$value")
done < <(echo $'1\n2\n3\n')
```

---

`read` always reads a single line of input; the `-d` option changes `read`'s idea of what terminates a line. An example:

```
$ while read -d'#' value; do
>    echo "$value"
> done << EOF
> a#b#c#
> EOF
a
b
c
```

Comment: This is great. I hadn't thought of using multiple `read`s. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The "problem" here is that `read` returns non-zero when it reaches `EOF` which happens when the delimiter isn't at the end of the input.

So adding a newline to the end of your input will make it work the way you expect (and fix the argument to `-d` as indicated in gniourf_gniourf's comment).

What's happening in your example is that `read` is scanning for `\` and hitting `EOF` before finding it. Then the input line is being split on `\n` (because of `IFS`) and assigned to `$a`, `$b` and `$c`. Then `read` is returning non-zero.

Using `-d` for this is fine but `\n` is the default delimiter so you aren't changing anything if you do that and if you *had* gotten the delimiter correct (`-d $'\n'`) in the first place you would have seen your example not work at all (though it would have returned `0` from read). (See http://ideone.com/MWvgu7)

A common idiom when using `read` (mostly with non-standard values for `-d` is to test for `read`'s return value **and** whether the variable assigned to has a value. `read -d '' line || [ "$line" ]` for example. Which works even when read fails on the last "line" of input because of a missing terminator at the end.

So to get your example working you want to either use multiple `read` calls the way chepner indicated or (if you really want a single call) then you want (See http://ideone.com/xTL8Yn):

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' a b c < <(printf '1 1\n2 2\n3 3')
echo $?
printf '[%s]\n' "$a" "$b" "$c"
```

And adding `\0` to the end of the input stream (e.g. `printf '1 1\n2 2\n3 3\0'`) or putting `|| [ "$a" ]` at the end will avoid the failure return from the `read` call.

The setting of `IFS` for read is to prevent the shell from word-splitting on spaces and breaking up my input incorrectly. `-d ''` is `read` on `\0`.