# why read command reads all words into first name

Tags: bash

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=','

read a b c d e f g  <<< $(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7") # <- this could be any other commands, I am just making up a dummy command call

echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
```

I expected it to output

```
1
2
3
```

But instead it outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
blank line
blank line
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux bash: Multiple variable assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952404/linux-bash-multiple-variable-assignment)

Comment: You just need to quote the command sub `"$()"` and it would work how you expect, the `,` are being expanded prematurely otherwise.

Comment: This might be a variant of a here-string bug fixed in 4.3. If you quote the command substitution, each variable is set to a different number as you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use it like this:

```
IFS=, read a b c d e f g  <<< "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
```

Use `IFS` in same line as `read` to avoid cluttering the current shell environment.

And avoid using **command substitution** just to capture the output of a single `echo` command.

If you want to use a command's output in `read` then better use [**process substitution**](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) in `bash`:

```
IFS=, read a b c d e f g < <(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Hi anubhava, Could you explain what "< <(command)" means? Was googling it but found nothing helpful.. Especially why there is a space between two "<"?

Comment: That is called *process substitution*. Just Google it I am on mobile otherwise I could give you a direct link also.

Comment: `And definitely don't use command substitution with here-string.`, why not ?

Comment: Thanks again! For others looking for process substitution, I am pasting a link to it here: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html

Comment: For more background why your original fails, I think there is still a bug with here strings. `bash` appears to be incorrectly applying word splitting to the result of the command substitution, so that `read` sees "1 2 3 4 5 6 7" as its input. Since `IFS=,`, `read` considers the entire string a single word and assigns it to `a`. Note that `read a b c d e f g <<< 1,2,3,4,5,6,7` would work correctly, as would `read ... <<< "$(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")"`.

Comment: In general, there should be no problem with using a command substitution with a here string. Using a command substitution simply to capture the output of `echo` is redundant, as you can simply replace it with the desired string.

Comment: @SevenHong: Thank for posting the link, I have updated it into my answer.

Comment: @chepner: Yes I agree, `IFS=, read a b c d e f g  <<< $(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")` woks fine as well. What I was suggesting that with `echo` it is redundant and for getting output of a command prefer process substitution.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
read a b c d e f g  <<< "$(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")"
echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
```

Note the quoting: `"$( ...)"`. Without it, the string is split and becomes

```
$(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")     ===>    1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Giving `1 2 3 4 5 6 7` to read produces no splitting, as the IFS is `,`.

Of course, this also works (IFS only apply to the executed command: read):

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=',' read a b c d e f g  <<< "$(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")"
echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
```

And is even better like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=',' read a b c d e f g  <<< "1,2,3,4,5,6,7"
echo $a; echo $b; echo $c
```

You do not need to "execute an echo" to get a variable, you already have it.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, your code is correct. There is a bug in here-string handling in `bash` 4.3 and earlier that incorrectly applies word-splitting to the unquoted expansion of the command substitution. The following would work around the bug:

```
# Quote the expansion to prevent bash from splitting the expansion
# to 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
$ read a b c d e f g <<< "$(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")"
```

as would

```
# A regular string is not split
$ read a b c d e f g <<< 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

In `bash` 4.4, this seems to be fixed:

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION
4.4.0(1)-beta
$ IFS=,
$ read a b c d e f g <<< $(echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7")
$ echo $a
1
```

Comment: I just checked my bash and as you said, mine is bash 4.3, guess that explains why lol

Comment: Bash 4.4 hasn't been released yet, unfortunately,  so for now the workarounds are the only practical solutions unless you want to compile from the Git repository and run beta software.