# bash 4.4 not passing variables to sub-shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Bash 4.4 and 4.3 seem to behave differently with regards to passing variables into subshells or heredocs.

From @CharlesDuffy a simple reproduction:

```
export var=0; var=1 cat <<<"$(env | grep '^var')"
```

Bash 4.4 outputs `var=0`, bash 4.3 outputs `var=1`.

My original script for reproducing the problem:

```
TZ=Europe/London
timezone=Asia/Tokyo
echo TZ=$TZ
echo timezone=$timezone

date +%H:%M
TZ=$timezone date +%H:%M

IFS=':' TZ=$timezone read hour minute <<EOF
        $(date +%H:%M)
EOF
echo TZOUTER $hour-$minute

IFS=':' read hour minute <<EOF
        $(TZ=$timezone date +%H:%M)
EOF
echo TZINNER $hour-$minute
```

Bash 4.3 (Ubuntu 16.04) gives:

```
TZ=Europe/London
timezone=Asia/Tokyo
14:52
22:52
TZOUTER 22-52
TZINNER 22-52
```

Bash 4.4 (Ubuntu 17.04) gives:

```
TZ=Europe/London
timezone=Asia/Tokyo
13:53
22:53
TZOUTER 13-53
TZINNER 22-53
```

(On bash 4.3 both the inner and outer approaches give the same time, on bash 4.4 the TZOUTER gives the original TZ value).

Does anyone know why this changed? I've looked over https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2016-09/msg00008.html but I can't work out which change caused the alteration to behavior.

Comment: By "passing variables to inner shell", do you mean "honoring variables during heredoc expansion"?

Comment: To be clear, the bash 4.4 behavior strikes me as much more correct. `TZ=$timezone read ...` should impact only that `read` command's *actual execution*. It doesn't impact expansion of arguments to the command, so why would it be reasonable to expect it to impact the heredoc?

Comment: BTW, might you consider building a simpler reproducer? This one takes a fair bit of interpretation. I'd suggest `var=0; var=1 cat <<<"$var"` as a one-liner that demonstrates the difference in behavior concisely.

Comment: Also, those `echo` "statements" in the here document are never executed; they are just literal strings that get ignored because `read` only reads the first line of the here document.

Comment: This seems related to the same bug that would cause `IFS=: read hour minute <<< "10:50"` to prematurely split the here string in early 4.x releases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `var=0; var=1 cat <<<"$var"` outputs 0 on both bash 4.3 and 4.4

Comment: @chepner I've removed those echo statements - you are correct, I'd left them from an attempt at debugging earlier.

Comment: @DouglasLeeder, heh -- the herestring one-liner emits `1` on bash 3.2.57(1)-release., but you're correct that it doesn't differ between 4.3.46(1) and 4.4.0(1). So apparently we now have *two* changes in pertinent behavior over time.

Comment: See, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33476446/why-read-command-reads-all-words-into-first-name. `bash` had several bugs regarding environment modifiers and here docs/strings that have been getting fixed out over the last few versions.

Comment: `export var=0; var=1 cat <<<"$(env | grep '^var')"` *does* repro in 4.3, by contrast.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks, I've edited the question to put your repo at the top. I guess we expected prefixed variables to override the environment over the entire command, not just the read statement. I've fixed our real code to just put the prefix inside the $() instead. But I think it's still an interesting change in behavior?

Comment: @DouglasLeeder, consider `export var=0; var=1 echo "$(echo "$var")"` -- in **every** POSIX-compliant shell that will echo `0`, not `1`. The `1` in the heredoc is inconsistent in this respect -- hence it being the pre-4.4 behavior that was surprising.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy `var=0 ; var=1 echo $var` will also echo `0` - I assume because the variable expansion happens before the var=1 is applied?

Comment: Of course it's a change in behavior; your code depended on a bug, and that bug got fixed. Precommand modifiers have never been documented to affect arguments or redirection to commands, only the environment in which command lookup and execution takes place.

Comment: @chepner I did look at the change notes for 4.4 but couldn't spot the change there - do you happen to know if there is a bug report or what line in the change log reports the bug fix? I've also looked at https://fossies.org/diffs/bash/4.3.46_vs_4.4/CHANGES-diff.html - maybe "Fixed a bug that resulted in alias expansion in redirections."?

Comment: maybe "z.  Bash no longer splits the expansion of here-strings, as the documentation has always said."

Comment: @DouglasLeeder Not all bugs are mentioned explicitly in the change log, and some bugs go unreported but are nonetheless fixed as a side effects of other changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the detailed changelog entry from 2014-12-3:

> `subst.c`
>
> - `command_substitute`: if running command substitution as part of
>     expanding a redirection `(expanding_redir == 1)`, flush any temporary
>     environment we've inherited as part of this command, since we are not
>     supposed to have access to the temporary environment.  Since
>     `expanding_redir` only controls access to the temporary environment for
>     variable lookup and binding, we can turn it off in the subshell

Specifically, the following new code is added:

```
  if (expanding_redir)
    {
      flush_temporary_env ();
      expanding_redir = 0;
    }
```

...which simply removes all contents of the `temporary_env` hash table, preventing temporary environment variables from being inappropriately expanded when `merge_temporary_env()` is invoked in `execute_simple_command()` during redirection-related expansions.

Answer (score 1):

This changed because `bash` 4.3 incorrectly applied the precommand modifier to the evaluation of the command substitution in the here document. In

```
IFS=':' TZ=$timezone read hour minute <<EOF
$(date +%H:%M)
EOF
```

both the change to `IFS` and to `TZ` should *only* be visible to the `read` command itself, not the `date` command. The above should work identically to

```
dateStr=$(date +%H:%M)
IFS=':' TZ=$timezone read hour minute <<EOF
$dateStr
EOF
```

This bug was fixed in `bash` 4.4, I suspect as part of a general audit of the code related to the evaluation of here documents and here strings. Some related bugs were fixed in 4.3, but others persisted.

Answer (score -1):

The difference between the two environments may be that TZ is exported or not

```
(
    export TZ
    IFS=':' TZ=$timezone read hour minute <<EOF
        $(date +%H:%M)
EOF
    echo TZOUTER $hour-$minute
)

(
    IFS=':' TZ=$timezone read hour minute <<EOF
        $(date +%H:%M)
EOF
    echo TZOUTER $hour-$minute
)
```

EDIT
To avoid variable expansion inside here-doc add single quotes around EOF

```
IFS=':' TZ=$timezone read hour minute <<'EOF'
    $(date +%H:%M)
EOF
```

But here it's expected to expand shell command, so the clearest

```
(
    TZ=$timezone 
    IFS=':' read hour minute <<EOF
        $(date +%H:%M)
EOF
)
```

the other is more ambiguous because parameter applies to read command but it is not clear if it should apply to heredoc substitution

Comment: I've altered the script to export TZ at the top, and I still see the difference.

Comment: It's not a question of whether it's exported -- we *know* it's exported; it's a question of *with which value* it's exported, and what specific change between the two bash versions altered that behavior.

Comment: yes, saw after, I just tested with export and without and could see different results, but it may be a bug here-doc