# How to get first and last element from a csv column

Tags: bash, shell, parsing, csv, unix

I have a csv file with the following format:

```
Time, Field1, Field2,
1000, 1,      2,
1001, 3,      4,
1002, 5,      6,
```

I want to get the first and last element from the time column and store them in variables in my bash script.

So, based in this example I need:

```
$start=1000
$end=1002
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a lot of alternatives. Here are some of them:

**Using `head`, `tail` and `cut`**

```
$start=$(head -n2 file.csv | tail -n1 | cut -d',' -f1)
$end=$(tail -n1 file.csv | cut -d',' -f1)
```

**Using `awk`**

```
$start=$(awk -F',' 'NR==2{print $1}' file.csv)
$end=$(awk -F',' 'END{print $1}' file.csv)
```

**One-Liner using `awk` (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1952480/974822))**

```
read start finish <<< $(awk -F',' 'NR==2{print $1}END{print $1}' file.csv)
```

**Another One-Liner using `awk`**

```
read -d'\n' start finish < <(awk -F',' 'NR==2{print $1}END{print $1}' file.csv)
```

Comment: Loving that third one. Didn't know about `read var1 var2 <<< ` Now that's what I call high quality H2O.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `while` loop like this:

```
while IFS=',' read -r c _; do
   ((end=c))
   ((start==0 && c>0)) && start=$c
done < file.csv
```

Check variables:

```
declare -p start end
declare -- start="1000"
declare -- end="1002"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, try this:

```
start_end(){
 start=$(cat csv.file | head -n +2 | tail -n 1 | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')
 end=$(cat csv.file | tail -n 1 | awk -F ',' '{print $1}')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed -n 's/,.*//;2p;$p' file.csv` to extract the first and last fields from the first column. From its output, you can separate each of them and read it into a variable like so:

```
{ 
    read start
    read end
} < <(sed -n 's/,.*//;2p;$p' file.csv)
```

The first `read` reads the first line into the variable `$start`, while the second `read` reads the second line of the output into the variable `$end`.