# How to store json key value pair in and store it in one variable in linux

Tags: json, bash, shell, centos7, psql

I am calling python command which will return data is JSON key-value pair.

I have put python command and other command in one shell script named as - a.sh

Code (a.sh):

```
cd /home/drg/Code/dth

a=$(python3 main.py -z shell -y droub -i 56)

echo "$a"
```

When I am calling this script I am getting output as:

```
{'password': 'XYZ', 'name': 'Stguy', 'port': '5412', 'host': 'igtet', 'db_name': 'test3'}
```

And after getting this output I want to pass the output value like password, name to psql command to run postgresql query.

So, what I want is that I should be able to store password value in one variable, name in one variable like:

```
a= xyz
b=Stguy
p= port
```

So, that I can use this variables to pass in psql query as:

```
psql -h $a -p $p -U $b -d $db -c "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS  ${sname,,};"
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Note: Env is linux(Centos 8)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

One way of solving this could be a combination of `jq` for value extraction and shell-builtin `read` for [multiple variable assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1952404/linux-bash-multiple-variable-assignment):

```
JSON='{"name": "Stguy", "port": 5412, "host": "igtet", "db_name": "test3"}'
read -r a b c <<<$( echo $JSON | jq -r '"\(.host) \(.port) \(.name)"' )
echo "a: $a, b: $b, c: $c"
```

- doing `jq` string interpolation `"\( )"` to print result in one line

Comment: Thanks @dnltinney for your response. I have tried your way but its giving me this issue: "parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 12".

For this line: "read -r h p n  <<<$( echo $a | jq -r '"\(.host) \(.port) \(.name)"' )"

Can u please help me with this?!

Comment: @Dragon looks like the JSON is malformed. Make sure `jq` can parse correctly. A quick test `echo $a | jq -r "."` can confirm this. Also please note the use of single and double quotes `'` and `"` in the example with `jq` ! The double quotes are used for string-interpolation and single-quotes wrap the whole jq-expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can aslo go with `sed` or `awk`:

```
PSQL="$( python3 main.py -z shell -y droub -i 56 | sed "s/^[^:]*: *'\([^']*\)'[^:]*: *'\([^']*\)'[^:]*: *'\([^']*\)'[^:]*: *'\([^']*\)'[^:]*: *'\([^']*\)'}/psql -h '\4' -p '\1' -U '\2' -d '\5'/")"
[ "${PSQL:0:5}" = "psql " ] && ${PSQL} -c "CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS  ${sname,,};"
```

**For security consideration**, i urge you anyway to avoid passing account data (user passwd) through environment variables.

It would be better if your python script had an option to directly launch psql with required parameters.

Comment: Thaks @Zilog80 for your suggestion, I will try one time.